# How to know android ViewCell.ContextActions show event?

Tags: xamarin.forms, menuitem, long-click

How do I know if `ContextActions` appears on my Android device?

I would like to receive events that come from a **Long Click** item in a `ListView`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the **Clicked** Event:

```
<ViewCell.ContextActions>
    <MenuItem
        Icon="chat.png"
        CommandParameter="{Binding .}"
        Text="Chat"
        Clicked="Handle_Chat_Tapped">
    </MenuItem>
</ViewCell.ContextActions>
```

Handle the event in code behind like this:

```
void Handle_Chat_Tapped(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    var menuItem = sender as MenuItem;
    // whatever you want to do here
}
```

Read more about the topic in the Xamarin documentation: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/interactivity/#Context_Actions

Comment: Thank you for your time. Dannis :)
Thank you for your help.
But what I want is that if the ContextActions of the ListViewItem is selected, I want the ContextActions of the other ListViewItem not to be active.

So I would like to disable clicking on the ListView anymore when ContextActions is selected.

Comment: Got it. You should edit your question because this is now a completely different question from the original one I answered, so it's easier for you to receive an answer

Comment: Ok, I'm make new question